# Validating Collections in Zend Framework2

Tags: php, validation, collections, zend-framework2

people..
My problem is:

I have a form, with a Collection, so, I setted a CollectionInputFilter to this Collection..

If i send two block of fields (collections) to validate, and one field of one of this block is validated, the same field in the another one block is automatically validated too, even if is wrong or not filled.. 
I don't know what to do.. I tried a lot of tips.. but, none worked..

Someone can help me? Or faced the same problem?

Here my code:

```
class ClienteEnderecoFilter extends CollectionInputFilter
{
 public function __construct()
    {
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'fieldOne',
            'required' => true,
            ));

}
}
```

If i send two fieldOne and one is filled, the another one is validated too!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the input filter for each collection item on to the `CollectionInputFilter` instead of extending it. Like this:

```
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

class ClienteEnderecoFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'fieldOne',
            'required' => true,
        ));

    }
}

$collectionInputFilter = new CollectionInputFilter();
$collectionInputFilter->setInputFilter(new ClienteEnderecoFilter());
```

Comment: That obviously won't work since `ClienteEnderecoFilter` doesn't have an `add()` method.

Comment: You obviously have to extends from `InputFilter`, but I forgot to mention that in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was rude. I was pretty tired of zend framework at the moment and while looking for a related answer I stumbled across this. It looked like another one of all the crap answers on zf2 out there and I was too tired to figure out what you meant. I've removed the downvote.