# ZF2 : Filedset validation is not working

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

My ZF2 Form Field set validation is not working but form validation is working I have tried same a form validation, but these are not working.

I have implemented `InputFilterProviderInterface` in field set but it is not working.

Below is my code:

```
class CompanyCreditLimitFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    protected $_curency = null;
    protected $inputFilter;

    public function __construct($name = null, $options = array()) {
        $this
                ->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))
                ->setObject(new \Application\Entity\PhvCompanyCurrencyCredit())
        ;

        parent::__construct($name, $options);



        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'credit_limit',
            'type' => 'text',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'credit_limit',
                'class' => 'form-control maxlength-simple credit_limit',
                'placeholder' => 'Credit Limit'
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Credit Limit',
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'mininum_balance_limit',
            'type' => 'text',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'mininum_balance_limit',
                'class' => 'form-control maxlength-simple mininum_balance_limit',
                'placeholder' => 'Minimum Balance Limit'
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Minimum Balance Limit',
            )
        ));
    }


    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array(
            'credit_limit' => array(
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim')
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array('name' => 'NotEmpty')
                )
            ),
            'mininum_balance_limit' => array(
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim')
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array('name' => 'NotEmpty')
                )
            ),

        );
    }

}
```

Form

```
class AddCompanyForm extends AbstractForm implements InputFilterAwareInterface {

    protected $inputFilter;
    protected $dbAdapter;
    private $_country = null;

    public function __construct($id = null, $name = null) {
        $this->entity = new \Application\Entity\PhvCompany();
        parent::__construct($name);

        $this
                ->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))
                ->setObject(new \Application\Entity\PhvCompany())
        ;

        $this->__addElements();
    }

    private function __addElements() {
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name' => 'creditlimitfieldset',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Credit Limits',
                'count' => 3,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'should_create_template' => true,
                'template_placeholder' => '__placeholder__',
                'target_element' => array(
                'type' => 'Application\Form\Fieldset\CompanyCreditLimitFieldset',
                ),
            ),
//             'type' => 'Application\Form\Fieldset\CompanyCreditLimitFieldset',
//             'options' => array('label' => 'Credit Limits',)
        ));


        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Save',
                'class' => 'btn btn-inline btn-secondary btn-rounded'
            )
        ));




    }

    public function setDbAdapter($dbAdapter) {
        $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    }

    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter) {
        throw new \Exception("Not used");
    }

}
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: It does not validating the field of field set. means I put the credit_limit empty but it doesn't showing any validation error message.

Comment: is there any one who help me for solve this problem

Comment: @Ravi are you [calling `prepare()` on your form](http://zendframework.github.io/zend-form/quick-start/#rendering)?  As I showed in my full answer below, the input filtering will not work correctly unless the array POSTed by the form matches the full structure of your form, and `prepare()` is what sets up the field naming structure for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, this type of problem is why I always build a separate InputFilter hierarchy matching the Form structure instead of relying on ZF's "magic" input filter builder.  Here's a great article on how to do that:

- http://circlical.com/blog/2015/7/6/zend-framework-2-forms-factories-inputfilters-and-hydration

When working with collections in this manner you'll need to add a CollectionInputFilter to the form's input filter for each Collection form element.  That class is completely undocumented IIRC, but you [can find an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21639976/1025589) and [the class here](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/blob/master/src/CollectionInputFilter.php).

---

I wrote a short script that reproduces what you're seeing:

```
<?php
<<<CONFIG
packages:
    - "zendframework/zend-form: ^2.0"
    - "zendframework/zend-servicemanager: ^3.0"
    - "zendframework/zend-hydrator: ^2.0"
CONFIG;
// Run this script with Melody: http://melody.sensiolabs.org/


use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class ChildFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct($name = null, $options = array())
    {
    parent::__construct($name, $options);

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'fieldA',
        'type' => 'text',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'fieldA',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Field A',
        )
    ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
    return array(
        'fieldA' => array(
            'required'          => true,
            'allow_empty'       => false,
            'continue_if_empty' => false,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StringTrim')
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array('name' => 'NotEmpty')
            )
        ),
    );
    }
}

class ParentForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name, array $options)
    {
    parent::__construct($name, $options);

    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
        'name' => 'childForms',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Child Forms',
            'allow_add' => true,
            'should_create_template' => true,
            'template_placeholder' => '__placeholder__',
            'target_element' => array(
                'type' => 'ChildFieldset',
            ),
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'submit',
            'value' => 'Save',
        )
    ));
    }
}

$form = new ParentForm('foo', []);

$data = [];
$form->setData($data);
echo "Dataset: " . print_r($data, true) . "\n";
echo "Result: " . ($form->isValid() ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
echo "\n\n--------------------------------------\n\n";


$data = [
    'childForms' => []
];
$form->setData($data);
echo "Dataset: " . print_r($data, true) . "\n";
echo "Result: " . ($form->isValid() ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
echo "\n\n--------------------------------------\n\n";


$data = [
    'childForms' => [
    ['fieldA' => ''],
    ],
];
$form->setData($data);
echo "Dataset: " . print_r($data, true) . "\n";
echo "Result: " . ($form->isValid() ? 'valid' : 'invalid') . "\n\n";
echo "\n\n--------------------------------------\n\n";


$data = [
    'childForms' => [
    ['fieldA' => 'fff'],
    ],
];
$form->setData($data);
echo "Dataset: " . print_r($data, true) . "\n";
echo "Result: " . ($form->isValid() ? 'valid' : 'invalid') . "\n\n";
```

and when I run it (PHP 7.0.9) I get this:

```
Dataset: Array
(
)

Result: valid
(wrong)

--------------------------------------

Dataset: Array
(
    [childForms] => Array
    (
    )

)

Result: valid
(wrong)

--------------------------------------

Dataset: Array
(
    [childForms] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [fieldA] => 
            )

    )

)

Result: invalid
(correct!)


--------------------------------------

Dataset: Array
(
    [childForms] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [fieldA] => fff
            )

    )

)

Result: valid
(correct!)
```

The input filter on the child fieldset is only triggered when the full hierarchy of keys exist in the data.  It's not a bug *per se*, but it's not what you expect to happen.